# How do I wait without sleeping the thread?

Tags: java, thread-sleep

I have an Epoch class that contains time slots. I am only allowed to build a "thing" (to simplify) in my time slot in the epoch. Here's an illustration:

[image]

So in this method I want to either return the "thing" or wait until it is my slot. If my slot time is already over I want to wait until the next epoch and then for my slot. My current solution works with thread.sleep(). like this:

```
   public Thing generateThing() {
    while (true) {
        var now = getTimeStamp();
        var activeSlot = epoch.getActiveSlot(now);

        if (!activeSlot.isPresent()) {
            this.epoch = buildEpoch();
            epoch.awaitMySlot(now, myaddress); //see wait below
            continue;
        }

        if (!CanIGenerateThing()) {
            epoch.awaitMySlot(now, myaddress); //see wait below
            continue;
        } else {
            return buildThing();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the waiting logic:

```
public void awaitMySlot(long now, Address self) {
    var mySlot = getMySlot(now, self);
    try {
        if (mySlot.isPresent()) {
            //wait until end of slot
            var difference = (mySlot.get().getStart() - now);
            Thread.sleep(difference);
        } else {
            //wait until end of epoch
            var difference = endTimeStamp - now;
            Thread.sleep(difference);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I understand it correctly then thread.sleep() wastes ressources, but I just need to wait I don't need to waste ressources. Also I think that sleep is not very exact.

Is there a better way to do this this without thread.sleep()?

Comment: This sounds like a classical scheduling problem to me. Have you checked out `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)?

Comment: "thread.sleep() wastes ressources" that is not true.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question have false premise: "thread.sleep() wastes ressources".

Comment: Do you intent to implemente it single threaded or multi-threaded? How do you want to control that whatever build `buildThing();` does, does not take longer to complete as one time slot or even an epoche?

Comment: I think if you want any useful help you need to better describe what you want to achive with your epochs and timeslots in general and how it is used.

Comment: @Ackdari Single Threaded. A timeslot takes 10 seconds and buildThing() just creates a POCO object.

Comment: @fjc I will look into ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor  thanks.

Comment: Or you could go with a simple https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html with a TimerTask. Still, the only thing you waste with sleep is that there is one more thread around. You can use a large number of threads before that becomes an issue.